# default platform tool set in Visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, vcxproj

I have installed VS 2015 and VS 2010. I have VCxproj and .sln file in VS 2010.

Now I want to Build the .sln file. I have open the project in VS 2015. But when i build it get build using VS 2010.

I want want that when I build using VS 2010 it should build using VS 2010 and If I open VS 2015, It should be build using VS 2015.

I have not define any toolset in .vcxproj file. It chooses the default toolset. Where I can find and how default toolset can be overwritten ?

Please note that It should be done using command line. I dont want to change .VCXproj.

Can any one have any Idea ?

Comment: Toolset mean Platform Tools set

Answer (score 0):

It's a project-level setting.  You can create one project for VS2010 and one for VS2015.  You also need 2 solution files.

[image: Platform Toolset]

Answer (score 0):

You can set this from the command line when building with msbuild, see this question: [Can I set the platform toolset from the command line when building with VS2010's msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544563/can-i-set-the-platform-toolset-from-the-command-line-when-building-with-vs2010s)

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same question. Furthermore note that there is an entry called 'inherit from parent or project defaults'.

What you and I (and many other people) want to do is exactly that - inherit from defaults and then change that default **in one place**.

You should be able to do this by adding user macro to a property page such as `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` such as:

```
DefaultWin32FlatformToolset = v140 <or some other value>
```

Except this does not work - possible an order of evaluation issue.

The kludgy way to do it (for VS2015) is to edit `Platform.Default.Props` in `MSBuild/v4.0/Platforms/Win32/` or `x64/`. First, find this line:

```
<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)' == ''">v100</PlatformToolset>
```

Then change the `v100`to the platform you want to use.
Then modify all your project files (one time) to use 'inherit from parent...' for the platform toolset.

I saved 2 versions of the file and did a copy/rename depending on what toolset I want. (You have to exit and restart VS2015).